# Chatter Rest API limit on comments?

Tags: apex, rest-api, chatter, feeditem, feedcomment

I am trying to use the Chatter rest API to get the comments of a FeedItem from the chatter feed. It all appears to be working OK except there appears to be a limitation on the amount of comments I get back.

For example I have a feed item that has 5 comments but with my code built following the Chatter Rest API documentation I only ever get 3 comments back. I can't seem to get the API to ever return all the comments, it only ever returns the last 3 comments.

My code is as follows:

**//APEX Class**

```
public ConnectApi.FeedItemPage feedItemPage{get;set;}
feedItemPage = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, testID);
```

**//APEX Page**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!feedItemPage.items}" var="feedItem">
      <apex:repeat value="{!feedItem.comments.comments}" var="comment">
             <apex:repeat value="{!comment.body.messageSegments}" var="segment">
                    {!segment.text}
              </apex:repeat>
       </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

And I coded it following the API here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_chatter_rest_api/

Is the fact that it is only ever returning the last 3 comments some form of limitation or is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a different method that you can use to control the number of comments that get returned. The parameter is called recentCommentCount.

Instead of using this method:

> ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(String communityId,
>   ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId)

Use this one:

> ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(String communityId,
>   ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId, Integer
>   recentCommentCount, ConnectApi.FeedDensity density, String pageParam,
>   Integer pageSize, ConnectApi.FeedSortOrder sortParam)

Here's a link to [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_methods) that describes all of the parameters.